# ggplot2 get barplot from absolute values Values

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

Hey I have the following code:

```
t<- rep(c(1,2,4,8,16,24,32),4)
y1 <- c(1,1.99,4.01,7.94, 15.98, 23.74, 27.17)
y2 <- c(1,2, 4, 7.98, 15.92, 23.77, 30.37)
y3 <- c(1,2.01, 4.04, 8.12, 16.19, 24.03, 31.14)
y4 <- c(1,1.96, 3.81, 6.46, 9.81, 10.26, 9.15)
total <- c(y1,y2,y3,y4)
rel.df <- data.frame(color=rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each=7),t,total)
ggplot(rel.df, aes(x=t, y = total, fill = color)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat ="identity", width=0.5)
```

And I want to plot a barplot, that shows each of my  ys as seperate group regarding to the t values, what I get at the moment is:
Is there any possibilty to allign the groups regarding to the t-values (1,2,4,8,16,24,32), without having that x-axis spreaded? So I want, that the x values have graphical the same distance, e.g the 4 group is as far away from the 2 group as from the 8 group.

[image]

Comment: If you make your `t` categorical (`factor` class), the values will be evenly spaced on the axis. `rel.df$t = factor(rel.df$t, levels = unique(rel.df$t))`

Comment: Since your values are exponentially spaced, you could also keep them as numeric and use a log transform for the scale, `... + scale_x_continuous(trans = "log")`

Comment: @GregorThomas thank you very much for the helpful answer1